# $document listen to key event in angular directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs

i have a need when the page load, the user press the enter, it will execute as the button, i write a dirrective. I use it as , but it has a problem, the directive was used in several pages, when i load other page, the action before was trigger, the more page i load, the more action it trigger, how to fix it.

```
dir.directive('defaultEnter', [ '$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?form',
        scope:{
          ngDisabled: '=',
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {

            $document.on('keydown', function(evt) {
                var which = evt.which;
                if (which == 13) {

                    scope.$apply(function (){
                        scope.$parent.$eval(attr.ngClick);
                    });                      

                    evt.preventDefault();
                    evt.stopPropagation();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the keydown handler whenever the element that your directive is attached to is destroyed by listening for the `$destroy` event.

```
link: function (scope, element, attr) {
    var handler = function(evt) {
        var which = evt.which;
        if (which == 13) {

            scope.$apply(function (){
                scope.$parent.$eval(attr.ngClick);
            });                      

            evt.preventDefault();
            evt.stopPropagation();
        }
    };

    var cleanup = function () {
        $document.off('keydown', handler);
    };

    $document.on('keydown', handler);
    element.on('$destroy', cleanup);
}
```

Comment: If off the key event, only the directive can listen key event. others will lose event ,for example, modal dialog will not disappear when i press 'esc'.

Comment: I listen to keypress in directive, so keydown is ok for modal dialog, thanks.